# How to link to external sites in a grafana table

Tags: grafana

How do I create a column of cells that contains hyperlinks to external sites?

I'm able to embed the text and pass it in via the data-feed, unfortunately grafana doesn't convert the plain text to a hyperlink.

For example, I'm able to create a cell with this text:

"https://www.google.com/search?q=hot+dogs"

How do I get grafana to convert it into a clickable hyperlink?

thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Grafana 8.1.x with `Table` panel type:

- create new `Override`, where you select/override column with that link value
- add overide property `Data links > Data links` where `Title` and `URL` will have value `${__value.raw}`

Comment: this works, thank you. Is there any way to modify the Title property, so that it's not a long string. Could you point me to the relevant docs. thanks!

Comment: @vgoklani you have typeahead suggestions there https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/linking/data-links/

Comment: this does not seem to be working with grafana 8.4 anymore.
My experience is that it always prepends the grafana instance url in front of the field value.

Comment: If you would like to access other table field e.g. 1 column is name other column is URL then use e.g. `${__data.fields.native_url}` (auto complete from Grafana variable editor is handly to find other possible values)

Answer (score 1):

As seen on [Grafana issue 24482](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/24482), the Table does not allow tuned formatting anymore (for multiple links, personalized label, icons, and so on).

The tip shown in the comments works, though: convert your table to table-old (JSON export, modify "type": "table" to "type": "table-old", JSON import, and then set your column to "String" with "Sanitize HTML" on)