# How do I properly format hyperlinks in a grafana table panel using data links?

Tags: grafana

I have a grafana table panel which lists errors of monitored equipment. I used the data link feature (with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68725569/17840398) answer) successfully to create hyperlinks in the table which bring the user to another dashboard where he or she can get more information regarding the chosen error.

Initially everything worked well but recently, grafana processes the link in a faulty way: instead of "http://192.168.115.56:3000/d/B1gXgIEnk/inbetriebnahme-tsk-influx?orgId=1&var-varSystem=3V4-2201-000169&from=1646232851000&to=1646238251000" (which is the raw text generated by my influx query), it generates a link http://192.168.115.56:3000/http://192.168.115.56:3000/d/B1gXgIEnk/inbetriebnahme-tsk-influx?orgId=1&var-varSystem=3V4-2201-000169&from=1646232851000&to=1646238251000, so it adds the prefix http://192.168.115.56:3000/.

This prefix remains, even if I try other formats of the value (${__value.text}, ...). Then I tryed to adopt my query output by changing it to "/d/B1gXgIEnk/inbetriebnahme-tsk-influx?orgId=1&var-varSystem=3V4-2201-000169&from=1646232851000&to=1646238251000" so that grafana can add the "http://192.168.115.56:3000/". But then the link doesn't work anymore since it becomes "http://192.168.115.56:3000/d%2FB1gXgIEnk%2Finbetriebnahme-tsk-influx%3ForgId%3D1%26var-varSystem%3D3V4-2201-000169%26from%3D1646232851000%26to%3D1646238251000".

How do I manage to get a correct clickable link in the table?

Comment: It seems to me, that this problem was caused by some grafana-internal processing.  Because now the links are generated correctly again, as it was initially the case.